# VS 2010, Coded UI Tests: Re-run failed test cases

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm using VS2010 Premium, Coded UI Tests.

Do you know how to re-execute failed test cases after run?
If test was passed after re-execution then it should be passed in result report.

Answer (score 5):

Not so optimal way but you could put all your code to `try/catch` block and rerun the test if an exception is thrown:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest
{
    private static int _maxTestRuns = 5;

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        //If the test has reached the max number of executions then it is failed.
        if (_maxTestRuns == 0)
            Assert.Fail("Test executed {0} times and it was failed", _maxTestRuns);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1();
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Call Cleanup, rerun the test and report the error.
            if (_maxTestRuns > 0)
            {
                _maxTestRuns--;
                TestContext.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                TestContext.WriteLine("Running Again...");
                this.Cleaup();
                this.CodedUITestMethod();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the way I would do this.

Comment: Firstly, I thught it could be better to use the `TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome` at the `Cleaup` method and rerun the TestMethod if the result was `Failed`. But, it seems that the cleaup method is called only for the 1st test run.

Comment: @Schaliasos The cleanup method only runs once because the frame work has to call the method for the Initialize/Cleanup methods to run. If you call the method normally then the attribute is ignored.

Comment: Thank you for this idea but having next question.

Comment: [TestMethod]
        public void JustForFail()
        {
            try
            {
                Assert.Fail("It's fail, just for presentation");
            }
            catch
            {
                //
            }
            
        }

Comment: Using the approach from the 1st post it's difficult to catch in report where Assert.Fail exception happens (because only exceptions from Exception class come to report using TestContext.WriteLine(exception.Message);).

Comment: @user1574853 No. `catch(Exception exception)` code catched ALL types of exceptions. Try this: Replace the `this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1();` with `Assert.Fail();` or open the `RecordedMethod1()` and change the properties values of a recorded control so it cannot be found by the test. Debug your test and see that the `catch` is always running.

Answer (score 0):

You could also generalize the method Schaliasos proposes, we could create a base class like this:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class _TestBase
{
    private static int _maxTestRuns;
    public Exception _currentException;

    public _TestBase()
    {
    }

    public void TryThreeTimes(Action testActions)
    {
        _maxTestRuns = 3;
        _currentException = null;
        while (_maxTestRuns > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                testActions();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _maxTestRuns--;
                _currentException = exception;
            }
            if (_currentException == null)
                break; // Test passed, stop retrying
        }
        if (_maxTestRuns == 0)  // If test failed three times, bubble up the exception.
        {
            throw _currentException;
        }          
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
    ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
    ///</summary>
    public TestContext context
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }
    private TestContext testContextInstance;
}
```

And then when we write tests we could inherit the class above and do this:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class NewTestClass : _TestBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod1()
    {
        TryThreeTimes(new Action(() =>
            // Assertions and Records come here
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
         }));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod2()
    {
        TryThreeTimes(new Action(() =>
            // Assertions and Records come here.
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
         }));
    }
}
```

I have been thinking about how this could be made even simpler, any suggestions would be appreciated.  This at least saves quite a bit of code if you have many tests that you would like to run often, maybe it would make sense for some to generalize the function TryThreeTimes so one of the arguments would be the number of reruns.