# Custom Data Driven MSTest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have XML spreadsheet files created from Excel that I need to use as the input for my data driven test. I can't use the `DataSource` attribute on my test method because of inconsistencies parsing the files with an Oledb provider. I was wondering if there is a way to have nested test results like the way the `DataSource` attribute does it?

I'd prefer for MSTest to show the breakdown of each row that was iterated as opposed to me catching a failed assertion exception and keep a collection of the failures. I of course want the test to run against every row and not quit executing upon the first failed assertion.

I'm not looking for answers that insist on loading the data via the DataSource attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on each of your `TestMethods` to deploy the XML spreadsheet file that each Test needs. It will be deployed in the Assembly's location.
2. In the `TestInitilize` method use the path of the Assemby to parse your file to your custom `DataSource` (maybe a list of objects of your input data).
3. Put your `TestMethod`'s code catch in a try/catch block. If an exception is thrown report the error using the `TestContext.WriteLine` method or append it in your custom results file (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801006/vs-2010-coded-ui-tests-re-run-failed-test-cases/11808448#11808448)).
4. Use a class level counter and at the end of each `TestMethod` check if the counter equals to your custom datasource lenght. If not, increase it by one and rerun the test.